# setup cron to browse all pages

Tags: caching, cron

On drupal 6 I use page caching and I would like to setup cron to browse all my pages on my website (30pages) before they get expired. What are best options to do that?
I know about boost module but I think it is too robust for my needs. Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "Browse pages before they get expire"?

Comment: In drupal you can setup minimum cache lifetime. After this period or after any cache flush, the cache is cleared and needs to be rebuild again by visiting pages. I am looking for some mechanism to browse my pages after caches are cleared, so my visitors allways get "warm" cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: wget is your friend when you want to warm up your page cache.

In more detail: http://linuxreviews.org/quicktips/wget/ for example. If you want to warm the cache for page requisites (all images, css, js etc linked to from any page) too, you can use `wget -p` which is not mentioned in that article.

Got more interested about this and found some Drupal specifics: http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/how-drupals-cron-killing-you-your-sleep-simple-cache-warmer

To summarize: just setup your system's scheduled tasks (cron on *nix for example) to run wget in a manner that finds all your pages before your cache runs cold.

Comment: thank you. Rregarding wget i found that it is designed to work without user interaction, like from within scripts. So do you think that it can be possible to run a wget script triggered by cron once every day?

Comment: Definitely. At least if by cron you mean the real cron in the *nix family of operating systems. Of course you can schedule tasks on windows too, for that matter - just not with cron.

Comment: Hi, so how can I set the cron to crawl my site? would it be enough to add wget -p command inside cron.php? I can set up the interval from my cpanel.

Comment: I did not mean that you should use cron.php for that. I meant specifically the same mechanism you are now using to run your cron.php, ie. your operating system's scheduled tasks (cron on linux/unix/bsd, scheduled tasks on windows).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I try to describe my situation more clearly, I really can not find a solution anywhere. My host allows to set up a crontab in adminpanel very easily. However, it is not allowed to run any script. I can only choose between setting up a http link or link to script (php). So I thing, for my purpose, I would need to put somehow commands from this page http://www.tutorialarena.com/blog/using-wget-xml-sitemap-spider-drupal-website.php inside my cron.php file. Or is there any other solution?

Comment: Well, not inside your cron.php perhaps but maybe in a custom module which implements hook_cron(). And you need to have permission (in php) to execute system commands. But executing system commands in php is another topic.